# add background image to ionic page

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to design my ionic app, and the first step for me is to add a background image. But it won't get visual.

I created a directory in my www folder named img, containing my image.

And in my homepage (home.scss) I've added this code:

```
page-home {
background-image: url(../img/logo.JPG);
}
```

This is the errormessage I'm getting:

"This inspection checks references to files and directories."

Comment: Firstly, is `page-home` a class or ?

Comment: Please add your page code so we can check if there is something wrong or forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I guess "page-home" is the name of your component selector.
Instead of putting the background-image directly inside it, you can try to put it inside  (if your .html has a , without code, it is hard to tell)

```
page-home {
  ion-content {
    background-image: url(../img/logo.JPG);
  }
}
```

Note: since your file name is "logo.JPG", I am wondering: are you trying to make some kind of splashscreen? In that is so, you may prefer directly put your image in the resources folder and configure the splashscreen in your config.xml